# How to change status bar background with NavigationBar background image 44px height in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, background, statusbar, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I'm using NavigationController with NavigationBar visible. I read from here [Bars and Bar Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html) that

> Black, if using UIBarPositionTopAttached. Provided by the window
>   background, if using UIBarPositionTop.

First, I make my ViewController conform to `UIBarPositioningDelegate` and implement

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTop;
}
```

I then use a 44px height image for NavigationBar

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_background"]
                                                forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and set window background color

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

but the result is that the StatusBar background color is still black. I want it to be green

Why and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be needing this answer, but I came across the same issue

I just used image of size (320 x 64) And covered the background area of status bar, thus black parts were discarded, You can add some other bg for top 20 pixels, which will cover the status bar